# Parse.com - TableView not loading cells

Tags: iphone, tableview, parse-platform, cells

I am trying to display a Table View in which I load datas from Parse.com . I do not use the latest version of the framework (because of other modules in my project I did not have time to change), that's why I'm using "keytoDisplay" and that I have no PFQueryTableViewCell class.

My question concerns the loading of cells: mine do not load ! I put NSLogs in every part of my code and the result is that the method (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object is not invoked.

I do not understand why... I verified I linked my tableview as Delegate and Datasource with my viewcontroller (I use Storyboards).

I'm a beginner, and I looked everywhere for an answer before posting here but with no success ... I also downloaded Parse sample codes but I did not succeed in solving my issue.

Thank you very much in advance !

Here is my code:

```
#import "LiveList.h"

@implementation LiveList

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"TestViewDidLoad");
    // Custom the table

    // The className to query on
    self.className = @"LiveList";

    // The key of the PFObject to display in the label of the default cell style
    self.keyToDisplay = @"Sport";

    // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled
    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;

    // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled
    self.paginationEnabled = YES;

    // The number of objects to show per page
    self.objectsPerPage = 50;




    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this     view controller.
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
   }


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[self setTableView:nil];
[super viewDidUnload];

// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

NSLog(@"testviewwillappear");

}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:            (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
// Return YES for supported orientations
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
// Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
} 

#pragma mark - Parse

- (void)objectsDidLoad:(NSError *)error {
[super objectsDidLoad:error];

// This method is called every time objects are loaded from Parse via the PFQuery
}

- (void)objectsWillLoad {
[super objectsWillLoad];
NSLog(@"test-objectsWillLoad");

// This method is called before a PFQuery is fired to get more objects
}


// Override to customize what kind of query to perform on the class. The default is to query for
// all objects ordered by createdAt descending.
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"LiveList"];

// If no objects are loaded in memory, we look to the cache first to fill the table
// and then subsequently do a query against the network.
if ([self.objects count] == 0) {
// ** There are other caching options in Parse iOS guide
query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkElseCache;
}

[query orderByDescending:@"Sport"];

return query;
}
// Override to customize the look of a cell representing an object. The default is to display
// a UITableViewCellStyleDefault style cell with the label being the first key in the object.


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:        (PFObject *)object {

NSLog(@"TableViewCell");


static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

NSLog(@"CellIdentifier");

UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

NSLog(@"CellIdentifier2");

if (cell == nil) {

    NSLog(@"Loop");

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

// Configure the cell

NSLog(@"ConfigureCell");

cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"Sport"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Lieu: %@", [object objectForKey:@"Lieu"]];

return cell;
}


#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
[super tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code you should have something along the lines of:

```
[mytableview reloadData];
```

You need to make sure that is in the block where you are retrieving from parse i.e. put it at the end.That works for me. It is to do with the call being asynchronous.

Cheers.